# Keyboard doesn't show for TextInput in react-native android

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react-native android app and the keyboard does not show on any of the text inputs, including the ones rendered by FBLogin. I have tried it in Genymotion, and on Samsung and Nexus devices. The keyboard does show on iOS.

I get this log message on startup.

"Unable to dispatch keyboard events in JS as the react instance has not been attached"

```
let options = {
      order: ['email', 'password'],
      fields: {
        email: {
          autoCapitalize: "none",
          keyboardType: "email-address",
          autoCorrect: false,
          returnKeyType: "done",
          enablesReturnKeyAutomatically: true,
          onSubmitEditing: () => this._submitIfFilled('password')
        },
        password: {
          autoCapitalize: "none",
          autoCorrect: false,
          password: true,
          secureTextEntry: true,
          returnKeyType: "done",
          enablesReturnKeyAutomatically: true,
          onSubmitEditing: () => this._submitIfFilled('email')
        },
      }

<Form
              onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)}
              value={this.state.formValue}
                ref="form"
               type={User}
            options={options} />
```